# PHP Request for SOAP XML

Tags: php, xml, soap

i've got this XML and it works in soapUi

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="xxx" xmlns:data="xxx">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:FindArticles>
         <web:request>
            <data:culture_id>de-DE</data:culture_id>  
            <data:vehicle_search_parameters>    
               <data:address>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <data:countries>
                     <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                     <data:country_id>D</data:country_id>
                  </data:countries>
                  <!--Optional:-->
               </data:address>
               <data:dealer_id>XXX</data:dealer_id>
            <data:show_dealer_vehicles>true</data:show_dealer_vehicles>
            </data:vehicle_search_parameters>
         </web:request>
      </web:FindArticles>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But I can not fugure out how to call it via PHP. I'm trying something like this, but get errors...

```
<?php
$wsdl = 'XXX';

$options = array(
    'login' => 'XXX',
    'password' => 'XXX',
    'trace'=>true
);

$params = array(
    'culture_id' => 'de-DE',
    'country_id' => 'D',
    'dealer_id' => 'XXX',
    'show_dealer_vehicles' => true
);


try {
    $soap = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
    $data = $soap->FindArticles($params);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

var_dump($data);
die;
```

It looks, that there is some kind of nested functions - how have I call it via PHP? I've tried smth like $soap->FindArticles('request', $params), but it still does not work

Comment: See you've enabled trace, I would suggest dumping `__getLastResponse` and `__getLastRequest` (body and headers).  Might shed some light.  What fails / errors?  Nothing in logs?

Comment: I only get 'Not Found', but when I use the XML in soapUI, I get results...

Comment: As in a 404 HTTP response or the API gives a text response 'Not Found'.  What API?  Is it free / public?  Do they have docs or maybe even a PHP SDK?